# Need help writing bash script for Greeting user according to system time, consider the minutes also

Tags: bash

For example:
00:00 to 11:59 "Good morning"
12:00 to 16:30 "Good afternoon"
16:31 to 20:30 "Good evening"
20:31 to 23:59 "Good night"

Comment: Sounds like a neat idea. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates

```
morning1=$(date -d '00:00' '+%s')
morning2=$(date -d '11:59' '+%s')

current_date=$(date '+%s')

if [ $current_date -ge $morning1 ] || [ $current_date -le $morning2 ]; then
    echo "Good morning!"
    # do something else
fi
```